# sticky/persistent xterm menus

Tags: accessibility, xterm

Is there a way to keep `xterm` menus in a way that is minimally accessible for users with disabilities? I know I could override every single action accessed via the menus to brand new keyboard shortcuts, but I want users to be able to open the menu and pick options with the arrow keys, for example. Or even clicking them with the mouse. I just want to overcome the dexterity requirement of holding down the mouse button and aiming the cursor before letting go while keeping the cursor steady over the option, which is causing trouble for several users.

I tried to override the popup behaviour of the menu by changing `popup` to `create` on the config file. I placed these lines in the user's `~/.Xresources`:

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override \
                !Ctrl <Btn1Down>:create-menu(mainMenu) \n\
                !Lock Ctrl <Btn1Down>:create-menu(mainMenu) \n\
                !Lock Ctrl @Num_Lock <Btn1Down>:create-menu(mainMenu) \n\
                ! @Num_Lock Ctrl <Btn1Down>:create-menu(mainMenu)
```

with the intent of overriding the [defaults](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings):

```
           !Ctrl <Btn1Down>:popup-menu(mainMenu) \n\
           !Lock Ctrl <Btn1Down>:popup-menu(mainMenu) \n\
           !Lock Ctrl @Num_Lock <Btn1Down>:popup-menu(mainMenu) \n\
           ! @Num_Lock Ctrl <Btn1Down>:popup-menu(mainMenu) \n\
```

But the menus still show up as transient, hard to use, popups.

Comment: xterm can be *compiled* with simple "tool-bar" support, which addresses this, but has a problem with resizing (see [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=406169)).  I use this configuration all the time.